# Explore about Site Templates

Tags: page-layout, site-template

I have been asked to **explore about Site Templates** but I haven't been provided to access the Site Templates Settings. Is there any website which can tell me about site templates in `SharePoint 2013` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of site templates in SharePoint

1. Default site templates.

the default site templates, such as `Team Site`, `Project Site`, and `Communities Site`. SharePoint site templates are prebuilt definitions designed around a particular business need. You can use these templates as they are to create your own SharePoint site, and then customize the site as much as you want.

When you create a new site you can find the different type of site templates as shown

[image]

As shown above, you have 4 default template category

- Collaboration .
- Enterprise.
- Publishing.
- Custom.

For more details about Template category check [Using-templates-to-create-different-kinds-of-SharePoint-sites](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-templates-to-create-different-kinds-of-SharePoint-sites-449eccec-ff99-4cf3-b62e-dcfee37e8da4)

2. Custom site templates.

you can also create your own site template based on a site you've created and customized. A custom site template is a way to package site features and customizations that you can add to a solutions gallery. Custom site templates are often used to deploy solutions in other sites or to provide site consistency within your organization. For example, you may have a standard policy on project management, and so you require the use of a custom project site template for all new projects.

After you customize your template you can `save it as template` to can use it with different sites.

**Note**: save site as a template is not supported by publishing site.

For more details check [Create-and-use-site-templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989?ctt=1&CorrelationId=c054e2f5-d55e-4c66-bbf4-e65f4e40a016&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102756445)